# Using Marshal to take object to xml in Camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel, pojo

I currently have working code, but its not using Camel in an efficient way I suppose. I was wondering if someone could help me use the Marshaling feature in Camel. Right now I'm basically calling custom Java code to do it. I've been trying the past two days to get it without this sort of custom Java code, but i keep running into issues that I honestly don't really understand. I think it would be easier if someone saw something that worked and told me how to merely get rid of most of the code by replacing it with a few route lines.

**here's my route**

```xml
<bean id="mockSql" class="tutorial.simple.route.MockSql"/>
<bean id="sqlToXml" class="tutorial.simple.route.sqlToXml"/>
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
    <to uri="bean:mockSql?method=populate"/>
    <to uri="bean:sqlToXml?method=process"/>
</route>
```

**here's my first java class/bean**

```java
 package tutorial.simple.route;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
 import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
 import org.apache.camel.Handler;
 import org.apache.camel.Message;
 import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
 import org.apache.log4j.Level;
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

 @XmlRootElement
 public class MockSql implements Serializable {

    private String name="name";
    private String job="job";

 private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("mockSql");
 ArrayList <HashMap> ary = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    public MockSql() throws Exception{
        // CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();


        log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        log.debug("constructed mock sql \n \n");

    }
    @Handler
     public void populate(Exchange ex) throws Exception{    


         MockSql m = new MockSql();
         m.name="my name";
         m.job="my job";
         ex.getIn().setBody(m);
         log.debug("populated mock sql");
     }
     @XmlElement 
     public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getJob(){
        return job;
    }
 }
```

**my second bean**

```java
package tutorial.simple.route;


import java.io.File;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


public class sqlToXml implements Processor { 
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("mockSql");
@Override
public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("MyProcessor started");

    /*String myString = arg0.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.debug(myString);*/

    MockSql m = arg0.getIn().getBody(MockSql.class);

    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.debug(m.getName());
    try {

           // create JAXB context and initializing Marshaller
           JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MockSql.class);
           Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

           // for getting nice formatted output
           jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

           //specify the location and name of xml file to be created
           File XMLfile = new File("C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\myxml.xml");

           String x;

           // Writing to XML file
           jaxbMarshaller.marshal(m, XMLfile); 
           // Writing to console
           jaxbMarshaller.marshal(m, System.out); 

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
           // some exception occured
           e.printStackTrace();
          }

         }

}
```

So, my attempt at trying to make this more "camel" like is as follows:

```xml
<bean id="mockSql" class="tutorial.simple.route.MockSql"/>
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <dataFormats>
        <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="org.apache.camel.example" id="myJaxb"/>
    </dataFormats>
    <route>
        <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
        <to uri="bean:mockSql?method=populate"/>
        <marshal ref="myJaxb"/>
        <to uri="file:/src/data/myxml.xml"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

and I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.12.0.redhat-610379:run (default-cli) on project simple-route: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V -> [Help 1`

**STACK TRACE:**

```
[INFO] <<< camel-maven-plugin:2.12.0.redhat-610379:run (default-cli) @ simple-route <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.12.0.redhat-610379:run (default-cli) @ simple-route ---
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.spring.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.12.0.redhat-610379 (CamelContext: camel) is starting
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ManagedManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is enabled
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Loaded 176 type converters
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.spring.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:487)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.doStart(JaxbDataFormat.java:247)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.doStart(MarshalProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:28)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:994)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:329)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2150)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:2080)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1868)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1740)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1579)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1547)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:221)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:176)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:73)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Could you please post the entire stack trace? I have had some experience with this and I  can probably help. Could you also show the XML that JAXB produced?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` indicates a mismatch of libraries. Please check in your Maven/Gradle/Ivy dependencies, if all Camel libraries use the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use unmarshal instead of marshal in your route.